# Localization jQuery confirm buttons in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, localization

I want to localize jQuery confirm buttons in WordPress. For this I coded in PHP file like this:

```
function Confirmation()
{
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script('eux-conf', '/js/eux-js.js');
    // Localize the script with new data
    $translation_array = array(
        'confirmation' => __('Confirmation', 'eux-loc'),
        'message' => __('Do you want to delete this item?', 'eux-loc'),
        'yes' => __('Yes', 'eux-loc'),
        'no' => __('No', 'eux-loc')
    );
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script('eux-conf');
    wp_localize_script('eux-conf', 'meta', $translation_array);
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'Confirmation');
```

And jQuery codes:

```
jQuery('.delete').click(function()
{
    jQuery.confirm({
        'title': meta.confirmation,
        'message': meta.message,
        buttons: [
                    {
                        text: meta.yes,
                        classes: 'widget btn primary',
                        id: "yes",
                        onclick: function() {


                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: meta.no,
                        classes: 'widget btn secondary',
                        id: "no",
                        onclick: 'close'
                    }
                ]

    });
```

**EDIT:** After David Lee's answer, I realized, if I write `"This is a String"` instead of `meta.yes`, I get `0` and `1` again like here:

```
        buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "This is a String",
                        classes: 'widget btn primary',
                        id: "yes",
                        onclick: function() {


                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: meta.no,
                        classes: 'widget btn secondary',
                        id: "no",
                        onclick: 'close'
                    }
                ]
```

I think firstly, I must correct my buttons parameters, but I don't know.

But this gives me like here:

[image]

You see, my buttos are `Yes` and `No`, but the code shows `0` and `1`. How do I correct this?

Comment: You have a typo in one line - `wp_register_script('eux-conf', /js/eux-js.js');` is missing a quote, should be `wp_register_script('eux-conf', '/js/eux-js.js');` (quote before second argument).

Comment: @JackBashford, Thank you, It is a copy-paste error. I am editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Confirm is just a plugin and not just one. There are one more plugins named jQuery.confirm. Which is your plugin [jQuery-Confirm](https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm) or [BootboxJS](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html) or others. I suggest that update your plugin. Because Jaydip Nimavat's example works.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
function Confirmation()
{
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script('eux-conf', '/js/eux-js.js');
    // Localize the script with new data
    $translation_array = array(
        'confirmation' => __('Confirmation', 'eux-loc'),
        'message' => __('Do you want to delete this item?', 'eux-loc'),
        'yes_s' => __('Yes', 'eux-loc'),
        'no_s' => __('No', 'eux-loc')
    );
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_localize_script('eux-conf', 'meta', $translation_array);//this one first
    wp_enqueue_script('eux-conf');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Confirmation');
```

and in jQuery:

```
jQuery('.delete').click(function()
{
    jQuery.confirm({
        'title': meta.confirmation,
        'message': meta.message,
        buttons: [
                    {
                        text: meta.yes_s,
                        classes: 'widget btn primary',
                        id: "yes",
                        onclick: function() {


                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: meta.no_s,
                        classes: 'widget btn secondary',
                        id: "no",
                        onclick: 'close'
                    }
                ]

    });
```

i changed the order, you need to localize first then `enqueue`, also i changed the hook to `admin_enqueue_scripts`, and changed the name of the variables since `no` is a reserved one.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result did not change... And I've realized now, if you write `This is a String` instead of `meta.yes_s`, you get `0` and `1` again.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(meta);` and show that into your question?

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
jQuery.confirm({
    'title': meta.confirmation,
    'message': meta.message,
    buttons: {
        yes: {
            text: meta.yes_s, // OR text: "'"+meta.yes_s+"'",
            classes: 'widget btn primary',
            id: "yes",
            onclick: function() {

            }
        },
        no: {
             text: meta.no_s, // OR text: "'"+meta.no_s+"'",
             classes: 'widget btn secondary',
             id: "no",
             onclick: 'close'
        },
    }
});
```